# How to access elements of an array of bytes?

Tags: c#, python, arrays, ironpython

I have an array of bytes `b` returned from a C# code using Ironpython. If I use `print b`the output is as follows:

```
   Array[Byte]((<System.Byte object at 0x000000000000241A [175]>, 
    <System.Byte object at 0x000000000000241B [164]>,
     <System.Byte object at 0x000000000000241C [152]>, 
    <System.Byte object at 0x000000000000241D [68]>, 
    <System.Byte object at 0x000000000000241E [194]>, 
<System.Byte object at 0x000000000000241F [154]>, 
    <System.Byte object at 0x0000000000002420 [22]>,
     <System.Byte object at 0x0000000000002421 [197]>, 
    <System.Byte object at 0x0000000000002422 [130]>))
```

Can anyone please tell the meaning of this (numbers inside `[]` and `System.Byte object at 0x00...`)? Also how to access the individual elements?

Comment: The numbers inside [] are the values of each single byte in the array, while the 0x000.... seems to be some kind of memory location address where the byte is stored

Answer (score 0):

Each of that are the references of the object inside your list, in this case has the type System.Byte, and the number in hexadecimal is the id of the reference. 
I if you take the first element de value will be 175 (in hexadecimal), is the value inside de []. So you only have to do a for bucle or something similar to get each value, the value before de [] are just the reference of the byte value in memory

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example may be?

Comment: What about now? I'm with the cellphone so for now is the best I can do sorry, in a few minutes I'll update if you want